# Displaying multiple pushpins on Bing Maps WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, geocoding, bing-maps, pushpin

Currently when I load my program Bing Maps will only load the first pushpin onto the map, for my example I have 4 pushpins which should be displayed when the application is loaded, what additional code would I add in order to make it complete all four.

In addition I have a couple of questions if you don't mind answering

Do I need to use a loop for each location?

Do I have to give each one an individual name? (Pin)

Can I link a access database instead of copying the locations across?

Is it possible to hide or remove pushpins when a button is clicked?

```
 Dim Pin = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()
    UserControl11.BingMap.Children.Add(Pin)

    Pin.Location = (New Location(55.852663, -2.3889276))
    Pin.Location = (New Location(55.956023, -3.1607265))
    Pin.Location = (New Location(54.840279, -3.2886766))
    Pin.Location = (New Location(52.819511, -1.8851815))
```

Comment: You're only four times setting the Location of a single Pushpin. Create four Pushpins instances instead of just one, and add them all to the map.

Comment: So should I just copy the two top  lines of code with different names 4 times or is there a short hand method?

Comment: Try something. That's the way to learn programming.

Comment: I mean I understand simply giving each pushpin a name e.g. pin pin2 etc...  but that would involve me having two lines of code for each, surely there is a simpler way of containing multiple name or self assigning instead of  having two of Dim Pin = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()
    UserControl11.BingMap.Children.Add(Pin) for each?

Comment: Eventually you may want to use a [MapItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.mapitemscontrol.aspx) with a Pushpin in its ItemTemplate, and bind its ItemsSource property to a collection of view model objects with a Location property. The WPF way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just these 4 pins you want to create, then you can use the following code:

```
Dim Pin = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()
Pin.Location = (New Location(55.852663, -2.3889276))
UserControl11.BingMap.Children.Add(Pin)

Dim Pin2 = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()
Pin2.Location = (New Location(55.956023, -3.1607265))
UserControl11.BingMap.Children.Add(Pin2)

Dim Pin3 = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()
Pin3.Location = (New Location(54.840279, -3.2886766))
UserControl11.BingMap.Children.Add(Pin3)

Dim Pin4 = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()
Pin4.Location = (New Location(52.819511, -1.8851815))
UserControl11.BingMap.Children.Add(Pin4)
```

Alternatively, if your location data is changing or you have an array/list of location information you can loop through, create pushpins and add them to the map like this:

```
Dim myLocations(4) As Location
myLocations(0) = New Location(55.852663, -2.3889276)
myLocations(1) = New Location(55.956023, -3.1607265) 
myLocations(2) = New Location(54.840279, -3.2886766) 
myLocations(3) = New Location(52.819511, -1.8851815)

For index = 0 to myLocations.Length - 1
    Dim Pin = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()
    Pin.Location = myLocations(index)
    UserControl11.BingMap.Children.Add(Pin)
Next
```

Comment: This works perfectly with the data I'm using but after adding It do seem to have one stray pushpin in the center of my map which has no fixed point?

Comment: Check the rest of your code. You are likely adding another pushpin somewhere. Possibly in the XAML?

Comment: The only other place I added a single pushpin was within the XAML code which I removed to see if the problem continues which sadly it does. It only occurs when adding your snippet above which I'm very grateful for by the way.

Comment: It's likely the for loop. I rarely use VB. I suspect the Upperbound is going to myLocations(4) which doesn't exist and thus displays a pushpin at (0,0).  I've updated the code sample.

Comment: Thanks after reading your comment I only need to change myLocations(3) instead of 4 as you said it provides an additional point at no fixed point.

Comment: Thank you for helping me this far, but do you know how what additional information I have to add to each line for a simple info page when clicked?